# Creating trigger and inserting new values

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, oracle11g

I have a Oracle 11g script to create a table, a trigger to update the primary key with a sequence, as well as insert statements for rows. When I try and run the whole script, it fails with the message:

Error(6,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "INSERT"

Here's the code:

```
    CREATE TABLE LOCATION(
  LOC_ID INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY,
  LOC_NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  LOC_STREET VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  LOC_CITY VARCHAR(127) NOT NULL,
  LOC_STATE CHAR(2) NOT NULL CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE (LOC_STATE,'[A-Z][A-Z]')),
  LOC_ZIPCODE CHAR(9) CHECK (LOC_ZIPCODE BETWEEN 1 AND 999999999) ,
  LOC_AREACODE CHAR(3), CHECK (LOC_AREACODE BETWEEN 1 AND 999),
  LOC_PHONE CHAR(7) NOT NULL UNIQUE CHECK (LOC_PHONE BETWEEN 1 AND 9999999)
  );

CREATE SEQUENCE LOC_NUM_UPDATE START WITH 100 INCREMENT BY 5;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER NEW_LOC_NUM
  BEFORE INSERT ON LOCATION
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT LOC_NUM_UPDATE.NEXTVAL
    INTO :NEW.LOC_ID
    FROM DUAL;
END;

INSERT INTO LOCATION VALUES(1,'Stubbs','801 Red River St', 'Austin', 'TX', '78701','512','4808341');
INSERT INTO LOCATION VALUES(1,'Backyard','13801 Bee Cave Pkwy', 'Austin', 'TX', '78738','512','6515033');
INSERT INTO LOCATION VALUES(1,'Emo''s','2015 E Riverside Dr', 'Austin', 'TX', '78741','512','4808341');
INSERT INTO LOCATION VALUES(1,'Mohawk','912 Red River St', 'Austin', 'TX', '78701','512','5670653');
INSERT INTO LOCATION VALUES(1,'Continental','1315 S Congress Ave', 'Austin', 'TX', '78704','512','4412444');
INSERT INTO LOCATION VALUES(1,'Broken Spoke','3201 S Lamar Blvd', 'Austin', 'TX', '78704','512','4426189');
```

So, is there a way to 'escape' the CREATE TRIGGER activity to insert values after 'END;'?

Comment: Simply do `:NEW.LOC_ID := LOC_NUM_UPDATE.NEXTVAL;`, it's shorter than `SELECT LOC_NUM_UPDATE.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.LOC_ID FROM DUAL;` - provided you run at least Oracle 11.1

Comment: You need a forward slash after the trigger's `END;`

Answer (score 0):

after trying a few ways, finally I got this that you need to execute all your DDL Statements with `Dynamic SQL` and use `SET SCAN OFF;` command before, because you use `:NEW`;

```
SET SCAN OFF;
execute immediate 'CREATE TABLE LOCATION(
  LOC_ID INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY,
  LOC_NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  LOC_STREET VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  LOC_CITY VARCHAR(127) NOT NULL,
  LOC_STATE CHAR(2) NOT NULL CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE (LOC_STATE,''[A-Z][A-Z]'')),
  LOC_ZIPCODE CHAR(9) CHECK (LOC_ZIPCODE BETWEEN 1 AND 999999999) ,
  LOC_AREACODE CHAR(3), CHECK (LOC_AREACODE BETWEEN 1 AND 999),
  LOC_PHONE CHAR(7) NOT NULL UNIQUE CHECK (LOC_PHONE BETWEEN 1 AND 9999999)
  )';
  execute immediate'
CREATE SEQUENCE LOC_NUM_UPDATE START WITH 100 INCREMENT BY 5';
execute immediate'
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER NEW_LOC_NUM
  BEFORE INSERT ON LOCATION
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT LOC_NUM_UPDATE.NEXTVAL
    INTO :NEW.LOC_ID
    FROM DUAL;
END';
end;
```

Comment: That's not working for me - SQL Developer doesn't like it. I get error message:

PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE" when expecting one of the following:

Comment: Sorry, you are inserting same key for primary key, let me rdit the answer

Comment: The insert statement should not include the loc_id (the trigger does this before the insert).

Comment: @Patrick yes you are right, I didn't notice that, I think problem is with `LOCATION` which is a reserved keyword

Comment: Doesn't look like it's due to the reserved word. It's seeming like I'm required to place each trigger creation in a separate script/file. Could that be the case?

Comment: not Sure, but the problem is not also with reserved word, I put the `create` code with `dynamic sql`, it's work very good

Comment: @Danomyte66, have you tried it with `dunamic sql` ?, answer edited

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues here. Data types, missing execution command after the trigger (e.g. `/`) and trying to assign a value to `loc_id` in your update statements when the trigger will take care of assigning a value to it.

- I would be inclined to use `NUMBER(10,0)` (use the precision that you
  need) for `INTEGER` which is acceptable, yet not conventional.
- With respect to the `VARCHAR` datatype, Oracle wants us to use the
  [`VARCHAR2`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF50950) datatype.
- With respect to using `CHAR`, a fixed width datatype for state, city
  area code and phone number, do you really want fixed width? I would use `VARCHAR2`.

I added an execute command, `/`, after the trigger and modified the insert statements to address the trigger activity.

Here is your ddl and dml modified:

```
CREATE TABLE LOCATION
  (
    LOC_ID       INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    LOC_NAME     VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    LOC_STREET   VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    LOC_CITY     VARCHAR(127) NOT NULL,
    LOC_STATE    CHAR(2) NOT NULL CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE (LOC_STATE,'[A-Z][A-Z]')),
    LOC_ZIPCODE  CHAR(9) CHECK (LOC_ZIPCODE BETWEEN 1 AND 999999999) ,
    LOC_AREACODE CHAR(3),
    CHECK (LOC_AREACODE BETWEEN 1 AND 999),
    LOC_PHONE CHAR(7) NOT NULL UNIQUE CHECK (LOC_PHONE BETWEEN 1 AND 9999999)
  );
CREATE SEQUENCE LOC_NUM_UPDATE START WITH 100 INCREMENT BY 5;
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER NEW_LOC_NUM BEFORE
  INSERT ON LOCATION FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  SELECT LOC_NUM_UPDATE.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.LOC_ID FROM DUAL;
END;
/
INSERT
INTO LOCATION
  (
    LOC_NAME,
    LOC_STREET,
    LOC_CITY,
    LOC_STATE,
    LOC_ZIPCODE,
    LOC_AREACODE,
    LOC_PHONE
  )
  VALUES
  (
    'Stubbs',
    '801 Red River St',
    'Austin',
    'TX',
    '78701',
    '512',
    '4808341'
  );
INSERT
INTO LOCATION
  (
    LOC_NAME,
    LOC_STREET,
    LOC_CITY,
    LOC_STATE,
    LOC_ZIPCODE,
    LOC_AREACODE,
    LOC_PHONE
  )
  VALUES
  (
    'Backyard',
    '13801 Bee Cave Pkwy',
    'Austin',
    'TX',
    '78738',
    '512',
    '6515033'
  );
```

Here is the execution of this ddl and dml:

```
  SCOTT@erp> CREATE TABLE LOCATION
      2    (
      3      LOC_ID       INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
      4      LOC_NAME     VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      5      LOC_STREET   VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      6      LOC_CITY     VARCHAR(127) NOT NULL,
      7      LOC_STATE    CHAR(2) NOT NULL CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE (LOC_STATE,'[A-Z][A-Z]')),
      8      LOC_ZIPCODE  CHAR(9) CHECK (LOC_ZIPCODE BETWEEN 1 AND 999999999) ,
      9      LOC_AREACODE CHAR(3),
     10      CHECK (LOC_AREACODE BETWEEN 1 AND 999),
     11      LOC_PHONE CHAR(7) NOT NULL UNIQUE CHECK (LOC_PHONE BETWEEN 1 AND 9999999)
     12    );

    Table created.

    SCOTT@erp> CREATE SEQUENCE LOC_NUM_UPDATE START WITH 100 INCREMENT BY 5;

    Sequence created.

    SCOTT@erpdev> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER NEW_LOC_NUM BEFORE
      2    INSERT ON LOCATION FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
      3    SELECT LOC_NUM_UPDATE.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.LOC_ID FROM DUAL;
      4  END;
      5  /

    Trigger created.

    SCOTT@erp> INSERT
      2  INTO LOCATION
      3    (
      4      LOC_NAME,
      5      LOC_STREET,
      6      LOC_CITY,
      7      LOC_STATE,
      8      LOC_ZIPCODE,
      9      LOC_AREACODE,
     10      LOC_PHONE
     11    )
     12    VALUES
     13    (
     14      'Stubbs',
     15      '801 Red River St',
     16      'Austin',
     17      'TX',
     18      '78701',
     19      '512',
     20      '4808341'
     21    );

    1 row created.

    SCOTT@erp> INSERT
      2  INTO LOCATION
      3    (
      4      LOC_NAME,
      5      LOC_STREET,
      6      LOC_CITY,
      7      LOC_STATE,
      8      LOC_ZIPCODE,
      9      LOC_AREACODE,
     10      LOC_PHONE
     11    )
     12    VALUES
     13    (
     14      'Backyard',
     15      '13801 Bee Cave Pkwy',
     16      'Austin',
     17      'TX',
     18      '78738',
     19      '512',
     20      '6515033'
     21    );

    1 row created.
```

Comment: So, I'm trying to run all the commands in a single script - looks like you're executing each statement separately (which works for me as well). When I try and execute all the statements in a single script, I get the error.

Comment: Also, if you have any other pointers on issues with my code, I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: I ran the set of commands as a whole (not separately).  Also, I added some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your script in this way (just a bit of formatting) and works for me in SQL plus (I had to change third inserts loc_phone value, since there is unique constraint on it)

```
CREATE TABLE location(
LOC_ID INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY,
LOC_NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
LOC_STREET VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
LOC_CITY VARCHAR(127) NOT NULL,
LOC_STATE CHAR(2) NOT NULL CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE (LOC_STATE,'[A-Z][A-Z]')),
LOC_ZIPCODE CHAR(9) CHECK (LOC_ZIPCODE BETWEEN 1 AND 999999999) ,
LOC_AREACODE CHAR(3) CHECK (LOC_AREACODE BETWEEN 1 AND 999),
LOC_PHONE CHAR(7) NOT NULL UNIQUE CHECK (LOC_PHONE BETWEEN 1 AND 9999999)
);
CREATE SEQUENCE LOC_NUM_UPDATE START WITH 100 INCREMENT BY 5;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER NEW_LOC_NUM
BEFORE INSERT ON location
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SELECT LOC_NUM_UPDATE.NEXTVAL
INTO :NEW.LOC_ID
FROM DUAL;
END;
/
INSERT INTO location VALUES(1,'Stubbs','801 Red River St', 'Austin', 'TX',         '78701','512','4808341');
INSERT INTO location VALUES(1,'Backyard','13801 Bee Cave Pkwy', 'Austin', 'TX', '78738','512','6515033');
INSERT INTO location VALUES(1,'Emo''s','2015 E Riverside Dr', 'Austin', 'TX', '78741','512','4808342');
INSERT INTO location VALUES(1,'Mohawk','912 Red River St', 'Austin', 'TX', '78701','512','5670653');
INSERT INTO location VALUES(1,'Continental','1315 S Congress Ave', 'Austin', 'TX', '78704','512','4412444');
INSERT INTO location VALUES(1,'Broken Spoke','3201 S Lamar Blvd', 'Austin', 'TX', '78704','512','4426189');
```

Comment: I cannot comment to other posts (still newbie here:) ),  but location is not a reserved word according to documentation ! http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b31231/appb.htm#BABHJHFE